# bootstrap grids col reorder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
                <p>A-1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p>B-1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p>B-2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

While in Large-screen devices it is Divided **inline** **A** first then **B** But in Small-screen devices it becomes **A** in the top and **B** in the bottom, What i want to do is keeping the SM-devices look as it is, But in LG-devices the **B** comes before the **A** in order, I've tried the **flex** col But it reversed it all in both screens.

Simplified:

lg:

B-1 B-2 --  --  -- A-1

sm:

A-1

B-1 B-2

Comment: i don't understand what you're trying to say.. can i have JSfiddle/Codepen/visual image for this?

Comment: @LakshmanKambam I don't know how to explain it on them But in brief, I want to reverse the columns in lg-screen order instead of  A then B, I want it to be B then A, But at the same time the sm-screen order stays as it is without being affected by the lg-screen order

Comment: What are the -- between B-2 and A-1 on large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any css . use bootstrap push and pull classes--

**Working example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       
       
       </head>
       <body>
       
  
                
            
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6">
                <p>A-1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-pull-8">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p>B-1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p>B-2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```